# unload html on mouseover html with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code loading HTML page in div content. And need unload previous HTML file then again load new HTML page. Please write if u can do it.
[Original code image](http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/7838/jsfl.jpg)

```
var please_wait = null;

function open_url(url, target){
    if (!document.getElementById){
        return false;
        }
        if(please_wait != null){
            document.getElementByID(target).innerHTML = please_wait;
        }
        if(window.Activexobject){
            link = new Activexobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else if (window.XMLHTTPRequest){
                link = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        if(link == undefined){
            return false;
        }       
        link.onreadystatechange = function () { response(url, target);}
        link.open("GET", url, true);
        link.send(nul);
}
function response(url, target){
    if (link.readystate == 4){
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = (link.status == 200) ? link.responseText : "Error: " + link.status
    }
}
function set_loading_message(msg){
    please_wait = msg;
}
```

Comment: An image with your JavaScript? I really hope you're kidding!

Comment: Its better to post your code here

Comment: When you say "load a new html page" you mean redirect the user to a new html page or just paste some markup returned by server-side via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you idea, using jquery.

This is your HTML code

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="javascript:loadUrl()">Load content</a>
<div id='content'>content </div>
```

This will be javascript

```
function loadUrl(){
var obj = $("#content");
    obj.html();
    obj.load('ajax/test.html', function() {
         alert('Load was performed.');
    });

}
```